# Service 'certbot' failed to build: manifest for phusion/baseimage:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: laravel, docker, certbot, laradock

Thank you for reading !

When I did `docker-compose up`on laradock, I finally got an error like title.

Does anyone know the correct solution in this case?

- Originally, I had that laradock, but I accidentally `docker-composer down` and tried building again. At that time I got an error like the title.

In this case, should I run `docker pull certbot /certbot` from dockerhub?

I am beginner for docker system.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for reading !

this is my error code.

```
laradock mycomputer$ docker-compose up -d
Building certbot
Step 1/6 : FROM phusion/baseimage:latest
ERROR: Service 'certbot' failed to build: manifest for phusion/baseimage:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try the latest Laradock version? I notice the certbot Dockerfile base image has been updated recently from `phusion/baseimage:latest` to `phusion/baseimage:bionic-1.0.0`

See https://github.com/laradock/laradock/commit/c9819508c1bfb7abc7826fa9437f92aa3c7c7b21

Comment: Thank you for replying! As you say, I had to check that Dockerfile(laradock / certbot/Dockerfile) and change from phusion/baseimage:latest to phusion/baseimage:bionic-1.0.0. That is the best solution! Thank you!